# Vim source code compile options with python2.7 and python3.x

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, vim

I want to use vim to write Python2/3 code, and I want to know how I can compile and run from the editor? Does anyone have any good suggestions, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

[**Pymode**](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) can run code using `<leader>r`. Here is a example:
[image]

If you're using vim writing Python 2 and Python 3, maybe you should compile a vim with `+python2`, and another one with `+python3`(then using the first one write python 2 code, the second one write python 3 code),

because Pymode and other plugin for python need `+python2/3`, but the problem is vim can't compile both with them.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple script to run python programs. All it requires is to have python installed on the machine. What it does ist run the program and show it's output in a overlay box in Vim. Problem is: if your program is interactive, it won't work. All it does ist display its output **after** the program is finished.

What I do is:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline)
    let isfirst = 1
    let words = []
    for word in split(a:cmdline)
        if isfirst
            let isfirst = 0  " don't change first word (shell command)
        else
            if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
                let word = expand(word)
            endif
            let word = shellescape(word, 1)
        endif
        call add(words, word)
    endfor
    let expanded_cmdline = join(words)
    botright new
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
    "call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
    call setline(1, 'CMD:  ' . expanded_cmdline)
    call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
    silent execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
    1
endfunction
```

This `RunShellCommand` runs a command and displays it in a popup within vim. Paste it in your vimrc.

For python I use this

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>r :Shell python %:p<cr>
```

in `<vimdir>/ftplugin/python.vim`

With this all I have to do is use `,r` (my `<leader>` is `,`) and it runs the current open python file and shows its output.